# Problem with Function Conversion Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

i'm converting matlab code in python code. I have this function:

```
function currentROI = ROI_refinement(croppedImage)
    [heightROI,widthROI,~] = size(croppedImage);
    currentROI = ones(heightROI,widthROI);
    
    % HSV filtering: pixels with hue, saturation or value 
    % outside of the specified range are discarded
    hsvFrame = rgb2hsv(croppedImage);        
    hsvMin = [0.00, 0.09, 0.34];
    hsvMax = [0.13, 0.52, 1.00];
    for iChannel = 1:3
        hsvMask = roicolor(hsvFrame(:,:,iChannel), hsvMin(iChannel), hsvMax(iChannel));    
        currentROI = currentROI & hsvMask;
    end   
end
```

What mean  currentROI = currentROI & hsvMask? And how i can convert this syntaxt in python?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator does the [logical and](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) operation. When operating on two arrays, the result is the element-wise logical-and of the two arrays.

Say you have

```matlab
x = [1, 2, 0; 0, 1, 2; 3, 0, 1];
y = [0, 1, 3; 1, 3, 0; 1, 0, 1];
```

`x & y` would return a `3x3` array, where `result(i, j) = x(i, j) & y(i, j)`

```matlab
>> x & y
ans =

  0  1  0
  0  1  0
  1  0  1
```

`a & b = 0` if either `a` or `b` is `0`.

In Python, you can do this using [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 1]])
y = np.array([[0, 1, 3], [1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 1]])

print(np.logical_and(x, y))
```

gives the output

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [ True False  True]]
```